# How to stage part of hunk with added newline at EOF?

Tags: git

Is there some way to stage *individual lines* of a file which has just been changed to include newline at EOF? I tried `add -p`, but it wouldn't split the relevant hunk into small enough parts, and it's well known that [git-gui throws a "corrupt patch" error when dealing with files without a newline at the end](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/BUG-git-apply-sometimes-says-quot-corrupt-patch-quot-when-adding-single-lines-td5434443.html). The relevant hunk:

```
 $courier:   "courier new", courier, freemono, "nimbus mono l", 
             "liberation mono", monospace;
-            
-$monaco:    monaco, "lucida console", "dejavu sans mono", 
-            "bitstream vera sans mono", "liberation mono", 
-            monospace;
\ No newline at end of file
+
+$monaco:    monaco, "lucida console", "dejavu sans mono",
+            "bitstream vera sans mono", "liberation mono",
+            monospace;
+
+h1 {
+  font-size: 2em;
+}
[snip]
```

I'd like to commit everything up to `h1` as a whitespace fix, and everything after in a separate commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution can work for you too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276752/can-i-split-already-splitted-hunk-with-git

Edit the hunk and add `\ No newline at end of file` at the end of the `+` lines.

**Edit:**
Now that I understood your requirement: Use `git add -p` to get into interactive mode, delete the +/- lines you don't want to be included in the add and save it then.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it looks like the better solution would be to edit the hunk and simply remove the lines I don't want to stage.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that add the newline?

Comment: I *do* want to stage the newline, an part of the whitespace fix.

Comment: "s/an/as/igmsx"